# Executing shell command from ruby console returning Permission Denied Error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell

Getting permission denied error while executing shell command from ruby console.
And the same shell command is working from shell.

From Shell..

```
tests@tests-workstation:~$ "`grep '^datadir=' /etc/mysql/my.cnf | cut -f 2 -d '='`/db_backups"
bash: /db_backups: is a directory
tests@tests-workstation:~$
```

From ruby console..

```
>> %x["`grep '^datadir=' /etc/mysql/my.cnf | cut -f 2 -d '='`/db_backups"]
sh: /db_backups: Permission denied
=> ""
```

Any Idea !

Comment: Are you sure your example from the shell actually worked? `bash: /db_backups: is a directory` sure smells like an error message. What are you trying to accomplish? Why is the entire command in quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to execute a directory and the shells are saying no; bash says no by saying "/db_backups: is a directory" whereas `sh` says "/db_backups: Permission denied". If you just execute the backedticked part:

```
grep '^datadir=' /etc/mysql/my.cnf | cut -f 2 -d '='
```

You'll almost certainly see no output at all and the reason is probably that your regular expression is too tight, something like this:

```
grep '^[  ]*datadir[  ]*=' /etc/mysql/my.cnf | cut -f2 -d'='
```

Would serve you better; the character classes contain a space and a tab.

Now that you're looking for the right things we can move on to why it still won't work. The `%x[]` quoter tries to execute its argument using the shell. When you feed the backticked grep stuff:

```
`grep '^[  ]*datadir[  ]*=' /etc/mysql/my.cnf | cut -f2 -d'='`/db_backups
```

to the shell, you should get a directory name that ends with `/db_backups` but you can't execute a directory. I think you want this to produce the directory name:

```
d = %x[echo `grep '^[  ]*datadir[  ]*=' /etc/mysql/my.cnf | cut -f2 -d'='`/db_backups].strip
```

Note the leading `echo` and the `.strip` call on the returned string. The `.strip` is necessary to remove the newline from what `echo` produces.

I think you're going through a lot of trouble for something that could easily be done with just a couple lines of Ruby:

```
dir = nil
File.open('/etc/mysql/my.cnf').each do |line|
    if(m = line.match(/^\s*datadir\s*=\s*(\S+)/))
        dir = m[1] + '/db_backups'
        break
    end
end
```

You could probably tighten that up a bit if you wanted but I think that that's at least less confusing than putting shell backticks inside Ruby backticks.

Comment: @sarnold: Thanks neighbor, West coast best coast.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want to get field 2 from the file. Then just do it in Ruby using split

```
File.open("file").each do |line|
   if line[/^datadir/] 
     print line.split("=",2)[0]
   end
end
```

There is no need to specifically shell out to call `grep`. This is inefficient and non-portable